# How wrap the new FormWizard in a view?

Tags: django, formwizard

Using the new formwizard tool (https://github.com/stephrdev/django-formwizard), How do I wrap the Django Form Wizard in a view? Instead of create it in the urls.py. I need to do this so I can access request and other stuff.

Does anyone have some example code for this?

Thanks in advance,

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of django-formwizard is based on Django's class based views.

You can access the request object by overriding the method you want in your wizard subclass and use `self.request`.